# Zero fill right shift in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
(byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
```

This is the Java code. I want to convert this code to Swift. But there is no >>> operator in swift. How can I use Zero fill right shift in Swift?

Comment: I have no experience with Swift, but after a quick glance into the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) it seems that Swift has first-class unsigned ints and will apply zero-fill shift on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `truncatingBitPattern` initializer of integer types
to extract a byte then you don't have to mask the value and it does not matter if the shift operator fills with zeros or ones (which depends on whether the source
type is unsigned or signed).

Choose `Int8` or `UInt8` depending
on whether the byte should be interpreted as a signed or
unsigned number.

```
let value = 0xABCD

let signedByte = Int8(truncatingBitPattern: value >> 8)
print(signedByte) // -85

let unsignedByte = UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: value >> 8)
print(unsignedByte) // 171
```

Answer (score 1):

Operator `>>` in Swift is zero-fill (for unsigned integers):

> The bit-shifting behavior for unsigned integers is as follows:
>
> 1. Existing bits are moved to the left or right by the requested number of places.
> 2. Any bits that are moved beyond the bounds of the integer’s storage are discarded.
> 3. **Zeros are inserted in the spaces left behind after the original bits are moved to the left or right.**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID29

Answer (score 0):

You don't need zero fill shift int this case because a byte is only 8-bits.

The code you have is the same as

```
(byte) (((val & 0xFF00) >> 8) & 0xFF)
```

or

```
(byte) ((val & 0xFF00) >> 8)
```

or

```
(byte) (val >> 8)
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik true , I assumed that if the code was simpler they could do the actual conversion. I will delete if someone answers this for Swift.

Comment: I'm getting wrong values with this code. For example : The result must be = -123 but with this code I'm getting 133 as value.

Comment: @BadCode for a byte these are the same value as `-123 & 0xFF == 133` or the difference is whether the value is assumed to be signed or unsigned. `(byte) -123 == (byte) 133`  whether byte is signed or unsigned.

Comment: By the way, which data type can I use instead of byte in swift. There is no byte as data type in swift.

Comment: @BadCode, `UInt8` is used everywhere to represent raw bytes in foundation code.

Comment: @user28434, It doesn't show negative values. How can I show?

Comment: Why do you need negative values? And in case if you *really-really* need negative values, just use `Int8`, `U` stands for **U**nsigned.

Comment: @BadCode Making `byte` only signed in Java was most likely a bad idea. Unsigned usually makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Zero-fill right shift operator doesn't exist in swift/objc, unfortunately. As an alternative / workaround:

```
// java
// let's say we want to zero-fill right shift 4 bits
int num = -333;
num >>>= 4; // num: 268435435

// objc
NSInteger num = -333;
num >>= 1;
if (num < 0) num ^= NSIntegerMin;
num >>= 3; // num: 268435435

// swift (assume we are dealing with 32 bit integer)
var num: Int32 = -333
num >>= 1
if num < 0 {
   num ^= Int32.min
}
num >>= 3 // num: 268435435
```

Essentially get rid of the sign bit when negative.